# Chemical effect on gravitation?

Tags: gravity, physical-chemistry

We know, that gravitation field of charged black hole is different than one of uncharged.

I this true only for objects with singularity or is true for all objects?

If true, then may we say, that gravitation field of chemical molecule has footprints of it's chemical composition and state and, in principle can be registered?

I know it is very small.

Answer (score 1):

In principle it is possible for a molecule that doesnt change its axes of rotation constantly I'd say. This is because the to first-order fixed spatial structure of the molecule poses a mass density $\rho(x,y,z)$ as any other masses do, too and produces a gravitational potential $\Phi(x,y,z)$ according to Poissons equation
$$\Delta \Phi = -4 \pi \rho$$
The vibrations and rotations pose complications to that, but I guess you could also calculate the gravitational signal from that.
After having a time-integrated signal you'd need, hoewver to solve an inverse problem like those typical in Geometrics: When onto the surface of Earth, you have a gravimetric anomaly, is this a dense object at huge depth, or is it a thin object just below your feet?
Probably you'd get somewhere deducing what your molecule is, up to a certain complexity with modelling, but I doubt you could assign arbitrary signals $\Phi(x,y,z,t)$ to all molecular structures that are possible.

Also given, that we aren't even able to directly detect gravitational waves from big events like merger of neutron stars or the big bang, I wouldn't hope on detecting molecular signals for a loooooong time in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Gravitational fields are not sensitive to chemical composition or state per se, except through the stress-energy tensor. The reason that a charged black hole has a different gravitational field is basically that the electric field has energy, and that energy is equivalent to some amount of mass, which is distributed over space rather than concentrated at the singularity. The stress-energy tensor isn't just a measure of mass-energy density; it also depends on the density of momentum and on the pressure. So chemical composition or the state of matter have no effect on the gravitational field unless they have an effect on the density of mass-energy, density of momentum, or pressure.

Note that electrical properties like the ones you've described may not even have any effect on the stress-energy tensor. For example, when you flip an electric dipole to point in the opposite direction, its stress-energy tensor remains the same, since the stress-energy tensor of the electric dipole field doesn't change under the flip. So not only is it impractical to use gravitational fields rather than electrical ones to find out about the dipole, the gravitational method gives less information even in principle.